# Match all URLs except certain URLs in Chrome Extension

Tags: regex, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to have it so that my content script runs on every site except for 3. I know there's probably a way to do it with regex but I'd prefer not to. Does the chrome extension manifest allow for exceptions?

If regex is the only solution and anyone knows the pattern to exclude these 3 URLs that would be great too.

```
https://www.linkedin.com/
https://mail.google.com/
https://twitter.com/
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts lists an option `exclude_matches`:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["myscript.js"],
        "exclude_matches": [
            "https://www.linkedin.com/",
            "https://mail.google.com/",
            "https://twitter.com/"
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm guessing you'll want a `*` at the end of those: `"https://twitter.com/*"`, et.c., to exclude the script on all pages on those domains, and not just the homepages.
You can also look into the [`exclude_globs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match-patterns-globs) option.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in this case, Regex is quite straight forward:

```
(www\.linkedin\.com)|(mail\.google\.com)|(twitter\.com)
```

)nly thing, you have to escape the dots (.) With Backslash (). Assuming the protocol should be left open. Else just put the escaped protocol up front

```
https:\/\/
```

Comment: Was looking for @Teepeemm's solution. This isn't bad either though, thanks.