# How to create an exception for <all_urls> in Chrome extension?

Tags: regex, google-chrome-extension, regex-negation

I've read [Match all URLs except certain URLs in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509752/match-all-urls-except-certain-urls-in-chrome-extension) but its accepted solution is only applicable to content scripts within the manifest file.

In

> background.js

I have the following **working** code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(handler, {urls: ["<all_urls>"] },  ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

Question arises because I need it to **apply to all urls except one** ( `*://*.facebook.com/*` ).

How to create this exception?

If the only solution is regex could you please guide me on how to properly write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filters you can to supply when calling `addListener` for `webRequest` events, i.e. the [RequestFilter type](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter), use [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) ([where the docs say this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#subscription)). Match patterns do not have the capability to do what you desire: exclude specific URLs, while allowing all others.

You will have to perform the exclusion in your [`webRequest` handler](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeSendHeaders) by checking the [`url`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#property-details-url) property of the [`details` Object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#property-onBeforeSendHeaders-details) which is passed to your listener. Doing so can be something like:

```
function listenForWebrequest(details){
    if(/^[^:]*:(?:\/\/)?(?:[^\/]*\.)?facebook.com\/.*$/.test(details.url)) {
        //The URL matched our exclusion criteria
        return;
    } //else
    //Do your normal event processing here
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(listenForWebrequest, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"] 
},  ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `^[^:]*:(?:\/\/)?(?:[^\.]*\.)?facebook.com\/.*$` be more precise?

Comment: @quackkkk, That depends on what you are wanting to match. `(?:[^\/]*\.)?` will match any number of sub, or sub-sub (etc.) domains (e.g `bar.foo.games.facebook.com`). `(?:[^\.]*\.)?` will match only one sub-domain (e.g. `www.facebook.com` or `images.facebook.com`, but not `foo.games.facebook.com`). What you use is going to depend on what you actually need. I had assumed that you wanted to exclude (ie.. match) anything in `facebook.com` (i.e. anything controlled by Facebook).

Comment: Cool, I didn't think about the sub-sub domain possibility - thanks again for the explanation @Makyen!