# How to not-match urls in webRequest.onBeforeRequest for redirection?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am writing an Firefox extension and want to redirect all urls as long as they do not end with .com. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns I can only find how to match a pattern, for example, `urls: ["*://*.com/*"]` will match all urls that end with .com, but here I want to find all urls that that does not match the pattern. I know there must be a way to do this, but I can't search the correct way to do it based on my very limited knowledge. Any help are appreaciated!

Comment: There's no way to specify such pattern so you'll have to match all URLs and perform the check explicitly inside the listener. See [How to create an exception for <all\_urls> in Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42816778). FWIW in Chrome it can be done using chrome.declarativeWebRequest, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest#precedences).

Comment: Got my job done, thank you! If you can formally answer my question, I'll then mark you answer as solution.