# How to block only YouTube URL that has the word "embed" in Chrome extension App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working with a Chrome Extension App. The background.js below allows all URL from YouTube and Facebook and it's working fine.

What I want is to only block or exclude YouTube URL that has the word "embed" while allowing other as per

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/video_id
```

That is, if YouTube URL link ever contain the word "embed" then block or exclude them while allowing other URLs.

Some Stack Overflow contributors suggest exclusion [via JS code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814357/how-to-create-an-exception-for-all-urls-in-chrome-extension) but I do not know how to go about with it.

Here is my **background.js**

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(
  async () => {
    await chrome.action.openPopup();
  },
  { url: [
    { urlMatches: 'https://www.youtube.com/*' },
    { urlMatches: 'https://www.facebook.com/*' },
  ] },
);
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "description": "My App Details",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["webNavigation"],
  "action": { "default_popup": "popup.html" },
"background": { "service_worker": "background.js" }
}
```

Comment: declarativeNetRequest is the correct solution, whereas the code in the question is unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply filter the url in the callback like below.

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(
  async (details) => {
    if (!details.url.includes("embed")) {
      await chrome.action.openPopup();
    }
  },
  {
    url: [
      { urlMatches: "https://www.youtube.com/*" },
      { urlMatches: "https://www.facebook.com/*" },
    ],
  }
);
```

Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/#event-onCompleted