# How to run specific script for particular website and general script for other websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

This question is completely different from [match-all-urls-except-certain-urls-in-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509752/match-all-urls-except-certain-urls-in-chrome-extension). This question is to run a specific script on the website rather than excluding it completely.

I am developing a chrome extension that requires a specific javascript file for 1 site. Another javascript file for all the other websites.

Here is my `manifest.json` file.

```
{
    "name": "See World Colourful",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons": {
        "128": "logo.png"
    },
    "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "logo.png",
        "default_title": "SeeWorldColourful"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/*"],
            "js": ["contentGFG.js", "jquery-3.6.0.js"]
        },
        {
            "matches": ["https://*/*"],
            "js": ["contentAll.js", "jquery-3.6.0.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab", 
        "tabs", 
        "storage",
        "contextMenus",
        "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

I was trying to run the `contentGFG.js` script on [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/) website and the `contentAll.js` script for all the other websites but, `contentAll.js` runs on all the websites including [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/).

Comment: This question is completely different from [match-all-urls-except-certain-urls-in-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509752/match-all-urls-except-certain-urls-in-chrome-extension). This question is about to run a specific script on the website rather than excluding it completely.

Comment: The question may be different, but the answer is the same. The answer in the linked question solves your issue.